# How does groupbox.Controls[i] or panel.Controls[i] work?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am new to C# and was wondering how `groupbox.Controls[i]` and/oror `panel.Controls[i]` works?

I have a panel with a bunch of buttons in it to represent a keyboard. I change the color of the keyboard button when the key is pressed.

However, when I do `keyboardPanel.Controls[2].BackColor = Color.Red;`, my spacebar becomes red.

My spacebar is `button55` and at `TabIndex 54`. Why is it my spacebar that turns red?

Comment: Because it was added to the form’s children as the third control. Tab indexes or control names don’t matter. You can make your own collection with specific indexes if you need them to. Or name them properly and use them directly.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen How did it add it as the third control? I put each button representing a keyboard in order. And how do i change the children control number/index?

Comment: You don’t. As I said, make your own collection in the order you want them to be and it’ll always be in order. Don’t rely on Controls collection.

Comment: Use View > (Other Windows) > Document Outline.  You'll see the buttons listed in Controls[] order, easily reordered with drag+drop.  It is notable that you should not care about this, high maintenance, the Name or Tag property is a decent way to find a control back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that yoor space-bar gets red is simple: `keyboardPanel.Controls[2]` is the space-bar. please pay attention that the buttons are not necessarily added to the `keyboardPanel.Control`s list in the order they are named. Meaning: `keyboardPanel.Controls[1]` is not necessarily `button1` and also `button55` is not necessarily `keyboardPanel.Controls[55]`.
Now, If you want to extract buttons by name you should use this:

```
keyboardPanel.Controls.Find("Button55" , true);
```

where "button55" is the name of that control and true goes for the option to search all the children.

But I think there is a simpler way to change the color. Using the Sender:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control btn = sender as Control;
    btn.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

and make this method as the event handler of all the buttons' click event.

EDIT:
If you really want to re-arrange the controls in the GroupBox you should visit the the designer. The simple way to get to the designer is to right-click on `InitializeComponent()` in the constructor method of your form and choose Go To Definition.

There you will find the order that controls are added. something like below:

```
this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.button2);
this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.button3);
this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.button1);
```

I my case Controls[0] is button2, Controls[1] is button3 and so on. You can re-arrange them like below:

```
this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.button1);
this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.button2);
this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.button3);
```

Comment: So there is no way to change the control number? Because I am currently using KeyDown to light up the keys being pressed, but using keyboarDPanel.Controls[i] all random keys are being lit up

Comment: I edited my answer to show how you can re-arrange the controls. However I still have to clarify that using sender object is a better way